# Disabled dates in react native datepicker control

Tags: android, ios, react-native, tcomb-form-native

I want to disable some dates in date-picker control in react native. I am using "Date Picker Android" & "Date Picker IOS", also if anyone has any alternatives solutions?.

the case i going to implement to my project : how i can disable weekends days in every week in the future ???

I tried control "tcomb-form-native" in github https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/ but i couldn't find what i need in this control

.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking you don't have any question marks in your question.
Please note that questions asking to recommend a library are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you for your feedback , I edited the question, simply the question is : how I can disable weekends days in every week  in react native date-picker control ???

Comment: I am waiting for any contribution from anyone here but no luck??